# If $\theta_1$ satisfies $\cos \theta = k$, then $\theta_2 := 2\pi - \theta_1$ also satisfies the equation

Tags: trigonometry

> If $\theta_1$ is any value of $\theta$ such that $\cos \theta= k$, then another value of $\theta$ that satisfies this equation is $\theta_2=2\pi-\theta_1$.

***I don't understand above statement, why do we need to subtract from $2\pi$? I'm even more confused when $\cos \theta=-k$.***

Comment: Why did you not include this with your question about $\sin$? The answer is the same: draw a unit circle and pick a value of $\theta$ and you will see.

Comment: This uses two ther basic properties of cosine: a) it has period $2\pi$, so $\cos(2\pi-\theta)=\cos(-\theta)$; b) it is an even function.

Comment: @kccu19 I could have but some time people complain about it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the diagram below.

[image: symmetry_diagram_for_sine_and_cosine]

By definition, if an angle is in standard position (vertex at the origin, initial side on the positive $x$-axis), the cosine of the angle is equal to the $x$-coordinate of the point where the terminal side of the angle intersects the unit circle.  Therefore, two angles have the same cosine if the $x$-coordinates of the points where their terminal sides intersect the unit circle are equal.  By symmetry, $\cos(-\theta) = \cos\theta$.  Since coterminal angles intersect the unit circle at the same point, any angle coterminal with these angles will have the same cosine.  Hence, if $\cos\theta = \cos\varphi$, then 
$$\varphi = \theta + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
or 
$$\varphi = -\theta + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
Notice that the angle $2\pi - \theta$ is coterminal with the angle $-\theta$.  Hence, $\cos(2\pi - \theta) = \cos(-\theta) = \cos\theta$.

Notice that the $x$-coordinate of the point where the terminal side of the angle $\pi - \theta$ intersects the unit circle is equal in magnitude and opposite in sign to the $x$-coordinate of the point where the terminal side of the angle $\theta$ intersects the unit circle.  The same could be said of the angle $\pi + \theta$.  Hence, $\cos(\pi - \theta) = \cos(\pi + \theta) = -\cos\theta$.  Moreover, any angle coterminal with these angles will have the same cosine.  Hence, if $\cos\varphi = -\cos\theta$, then
$$\varphi = \pi - \theta + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
or 
$$\varphi = \pi + \theta + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: You are the boss... Thanks a lot for detailed answer for both the questions. They said that for `tan theta` it is `theta2=PI+theta1`. I'm not sure why. Would you be able to update this answer for `tan`? Or you want me to post new question.

Comment: We have shown that $\sin(\pi + \theta) = -\sin\theta$ and that $\cos(\pi + \theta) = -\cos\theta$.  Hence, $$\tan(\pi + \theta) = \frac{\sin(\pi + \theta)}{\cos(\pi + \theta)} = \frac{-\sin\theta}{-\cos\theta} = \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta} = \tan\theta$$